# rails :allow_nil => true not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model for book listings and in my form I have a place for isbns. My model validation is so that users can enter only numbers and dash symbols. I wanted it so that it would still work if they left it blank.

listing.rb

```
  validates :isbn, format: { with: /\A[\d-]*\d[\d-]*\z/ }, :allow_nil => true
```

Problem is, when you submit the form and leave that space blank, you get an error.

```
1 error prohibited this listing from being saved:
Isbn is invalid
```

Why is this validation not allowing a blank submission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nil` and blank aren't the same thing: if your form is submitting an empty string, that's not nil, but also does not match the declared format. If you want to allow blank values, you need `:allow_blank` instead of `:allow_nil`.